# ngAnimate - Animation not triggered on repeated custom directive

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I want to use ngAnimate on a custom directive which is repeated using ng-repeat.
The animations work just fine if I use ng-repeat on a simple html list-item. However, as soon as replace the list-item by a custom directive element the animation is not triggered.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Code ( [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kUKuQJQBmVsqTr6ytRaA?p=preview) ):

HTML

```
<h3>Simple ng-repeat</h3>
<ul>
   <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="val in testValues">{{ val }}</li>
</ul>

<h3>ng-repeat on custom directive</h3>
<ul >
    <animation-test class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="val in testValues" test-val="val"></animation-test>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('application', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('mainController', [ '$scope', mainController]);

function mainController($scope){

      // just for demo purposes
  $scope.testValues = [];

  $scope.addItem = function(){
    var len = $scope.testValues.length;
    $scope.testValues.unshift('Value #' + len);
  };

  $scope.removeItem = function(){
     $scope.testValues.pop();
  };

}

app.directive('animationTest', animationTest);

function animationTest(){

  return {
    template: ' <li> {{testVal}} </li> ',
    scope: {
      testVal: '<'
    }
  };
}
```

CSS (uses [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) )

```
.animate-repeat.ng-enter {
    animation: 0.5s slideInUp;
}

.animate-repeat.ng-leave,
.animate-repeat.ng-move {
    animation: 0.5s slideOutDown;

}



@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
}

to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     }
}

@keyframes slideInUp {
from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    visibility: visible;
}

to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

.slideInUp {
-webkit-animation-name: slideInUp;
animation-name: slideInUp;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOutDown {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

to {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes slideOutDown {
from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

to {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }
}

.slideOutDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: slideOutDown;
    animation-name: slideOutDown;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind the directive to a `<li>` element which will then make your exact code work. So just change the HTML for the directive to this:

```
<li animation-test class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="val in testValues" test-val="val"></li>
```

And your directive would be:

```
app.directive('animationTest', animationTest);

  function animationTest(){

  return {
    template: '{{testVal}}',
    scope: {
      testVal: '<'
    }
  };
}
```

[CodePen demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/A8NxWO7tMIhU8IZsCAoR?p=preview)

Or if you want to make it your way you need to just add a class for the directive element ie. `directive-block` and then set the animations to the directive element itself like this:

HTML:

```
<animation-test class="directive-block" ng-repeat="val in testValues" test-val="val"></animation-test>
```

CSS:

```
.directive-block {
  display: block;
  animation: 0.5s slideInUp;
}

.directive-block.ng-leave-active {
  animation: 0.5s slideOutDown;
}
```

[CodePen demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/uteDDeypaCzCklnij4E9?p=preview)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replace` property:

```
app.directive('animationTest', animationTest);

function animationTest(){

  return {
    template: ' <li> {{testVal}} </li> ',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      testVal: '<'
    }
  };
}
```

or add css:

```
.animate-repeat {
  display:block;
}
```